# How to split String with quotes in content

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a String which looks like this:

```
"["xxx","yyy","zzz"]"
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to convert it to an array that looks like this:

```
somestring[0]="xxx"
somestring[1]="yyy"
somestring[2]="zzz"
```

Comment: What are the acceptable values for the data in the array and do you want to maintain the strings...(Inside of the string)

Comment: @AmitD thanks for your reply! but let assume that this string is dynamically obtained from web service, and it could contain for example 7 parts.

Comment: My question was more along the line of do you know that the string will always be X characters or longer or some other parameters in the source array?

Comment: @Jared seriously i have to be too exhausted tonight because i do not understand you.. it could happen that those strings would be different size i just can't control them, it came to me in http response, i just have to handle them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty hack

```
String s1="[\"xxx\",\"yyy\",\"zzz\"]";
        String s2= s1.replaceAll("\"", "" );
        s2=s2.replace("[", "");
        s2=s2.replace("]", "");
        String ar[] =s2.split(",");
```

Comment: i actually used this solution

Comment: This could be done in a single line (after declaring `s1`)... 
`string ar[] = s1.Replace("\"", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(",");`

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
"[\"xxx\",\"yyy\",\"zzz\"]".replaceAll( "[\\\"\\[\\]]", "" ).split( "," );
```

will result in an array:

```
a[0] = "xxx";
a[1] = "yyy";
a[2] = "zzz";
```

I hope...

[1 hour later...]

I confirm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for( String part : "[\"xxx\",\"yyy\",\"zzz\"]".replaceAll( "[\\\"\\[\\]]", "" ).split( "," )) {
        System.out.println( part );
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Comment: Works until you have brackets or quotes in the strings themselves.

Comment: @Vulcan OP clarified that it will only contain letters.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at input string pattern, `substring` will also work:

```
String inStr = "\"[\"xxx\",\"yyy\",\"zzz\"]\"";
String [] inArray = inStr.substring(0,inStr.length()-2).substring(2).split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inArray));
```

Will print:

```
    ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
```

**If you wish to remove quotes ("),** then write like:

```
String inStr = "\"[\"xxx\",\"yyy\",\"zzz\"]\"";
String [] inArray1 = inStr.substring(0,inStr1.length()-2)
                          .substring(2).replaceAll("\"","").split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inArray1));
```

Or you can do:

```
String inStr = "\"[\"xxx\",\"yyy\",\"zzz\"]\"";
String [] inArray = inStr.replaceAll( "[\\\"\\[\\]\"]", "").split( "," );
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inArray0));
```

The above two will print:

```
    [xxx, yyy, zzz]
```

Comment: i will explain my problem with more detail. I run HttpPost which result in getting response string that looks like string in my question (again "["xxx","yyy","zzz"]") i want to move those values (xxx,yyy,..) to variables to control them in codebehind, response could contains more strings then 3

Comment: That should be fine. **It works for any number of strings** e.g. `"["xxx","yyy","zzz", "abc", "abcd", "mnopqr"]"`  as long as you have `"[` in the beginning and `]"` in the end. If you are expecting more patterns, please share couple of them to get better understanding.

Comment: NO, you have to remove the quotes "

Comment: @Aubin: Updated the answer with that pattern as well. I think in your previous answer, regex wasn't correct. I see that is corrected now :)